# how to map a string insider a quote that does not contain number regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have strings as below:

- "record one","field a":"random a b c","filed b":"random a b c","filed
  c":"123"
- "record two","field a":"random a b c","filed b":"random a b
  c","filed c":"abc"

How do I extract value from filed c that does not contain any number using regex? I tried something like:

```
r"\"filed c\"\:\"([^\"\d]*)"
```

but it was not working. Thank you.

Comment: `filed` is not `field`.

Comment: If any answer does what you want, please consider ticking it as correct. A reputation of 1 is enough to do it. I remind you this because newcomers often forget to do so. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Say you have,

```
records = [
    '"record one","field a":"random a b c","filed b":"random a b c","filed c":"123"',
    '"record two","field a":"random a b c","filed b":"random a b c","filed c":"abc"',
    '"record ...","field a":"random a b c","filed b":"random a b c","filed c":"ab12c"',
    '"record ...","field a":"random a b c","filed b":"random a b c","filed c":""',
    '"record ...","field a":"random a b c","filed b":"random a b c","filed c":"12abc"',
    '"record nth","field a":"random a b c","filed b":"random a b c","filed c":"Xyz"',
]
```

What about doing

```
import re
rex = '"filed c":"([^\d]*)"'
does_not_contain_any_number = []
for record in records:
    q = re.compile(rex, re.DOTALL).findall(record)
    if len(''.join(q)):
        does_not_contain_any_number += q


print(does_not_contain_any_number)
#['abc', 'Xyz']
```